# Cannot get jquery.multiple.select.js to validate and pass to php the boxes checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using jquery.multiple.select.js v1.1.0 and cannot get this to validate and pass the output to my php mailer. My objective is for the visitor to my site to select from multiple options requesting a quote. So far, I'm able to receive the email with all other fields validated but in the email, I receive"quote for: array" but no selections. Also related, I'm not getting the success or error message on the page even though the email is going out. Can anyone steer me in the right direction? I'll include the page in question here, http://cptest.info/h2contact375.html

**here's the validation js**

```
var Contact = {

initialized: false,

initialize: function() {

    if (this.initialized) return;
    this.initialized = true;

    this.build();
    this.events();

},

build: function() {

    this.validations();

},

events: function() {

},

validations: function() {

    $("#contactForm").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "js/contact-form.php",
                data: {
                    "name": $("#contactForm #name").val(),
                    "email": $("#contactForm #email").val(),
                    "telephone": $("#contactForm #telephone").val(),
                    "message": $("#contactForm #message").val(),
                    "ms": $("#contactForm #ms").val()
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.response == "success") {

                        $("#contactSuccess").removeClass("hidden");
                        $("#contactError").addClass("hidden");

                        $("#contactForm #name, #contactForm #email, #contactForm #telephone, #contactForm #message, #contactForm #ms")
                            .val("")
                            .blur()
                            .closest(".control-group")
                            .removeClass("success")
                            .removeClass("error");

                        if(($("#contactSuccess").position().top - 80) < $(window).scrollTop()){
                            $("html, body").animate({
                                 scrollTop: $("#contactSuccess").offset().top - 80
                            }, 300);                                
                        }

                    } else {

                        $("#contactError").removeClass("hidden");
                        $("#contactSuccess").addClass("hidden");

                        if(($("#contactError").position().top - 80) < $(window).scrollTop()){
                            $("html, body").animate({
                                 scrollTop: $("#contactError").offset().top - 80
                            }, 300);                                
                        }

                    }
                }

            });
        },
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            telephone: {
                required: true
            },
            message: {
                required: true
            },
            ms:{
                required: true,
                message: 'Please select at least one'
            },
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element)
                .closest(".control-group")
                .removeClass("success")
                .addClass("error");
        },
        success: function (element) {
            $(element)
                .closest(".control-group")
                .removeClass("error")
                .addClass("success");
        }
    });

}

};

Contact.initialize();
```

**here's the php**

```
<?php 
// check if fields passed are empty 

 if(empty($_POST['name'])   ||    
empty($_POST['email'])  ||
empty($_POST['message'])||
empty($_POST['telephone'])||
empty($_POST['ms']) ||   
!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))    
  {     
   echo "No arguments Provided!";   return false;    
  } 

  $name = $_POST['name']; 
  $email_address = $_POST['email']; 
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
  $ms = $_POST['ms'];      

 // create email body and send it    
 $to = "myemail@gmail.com"; 
 // put your email 
 $email_subject = "Contact form submitted by:  $name"; $email_body = "You have received a new message. \n\n".                 
               " Here are the details:\n \nName: $name \n ". 
               "Telephone: $telephone \n" . 
               "Quote For: $ms \n" .               
               "Email: $email_address\n Message: \n $message"; 
 //$headers = "From: me@youremail.com\n"; 
 //$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";  


 mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers); return true;            
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It might be helpful if you give us more details, so it's easier for us to troubleshoot your problem and help you find an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome message. My problem(s) is two-fold, first and foremost I need the selections from the select to be sent to my email. second, I'd like a success message or even a redirect to a success page, just something to confirm to the sender that we received the message.
the PHP is sending the email, but the multiselect only sends "Array" in that section.

Answer (score 0):

give `name` to your field called `ms` otherwise it will not go to php because it identifies name not id and based on your condition checking it will always show *No arguments Provided!*.

```
<select id="ms" multiple="multiple" name="ms">
```

Try Using `$_REQUEST` in your PHP if `$_POST` is not providing the data to check.

**NOTE:** there is no styling added just expect it to send data to your php nothing else.

```
<?php 
// check if fields passed are empty 
print_r($_REQUEST);//it should display the send data
//rest of the code with request
```

[DEMO](http://main.xfiddle.com/60abc423/demo.php)

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, the print request did not work, when I sent a message from the contact form I still received the same message I've been getting, "You have received a new message. 

 Here are the details:
 
Name: test name 
 Telephone: 123123123 
Quote For: Array 
Email: testemail@testemail.com
 Message: 
 Test email with two options selected."

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to validate so validation plugin will not ignore the hidden `<select>` element.

The magic happens in this line:

```
ignore: ':hidden:not("#ms")',
```

add it to validation script

```
 //AjaxCall Code
 },
 ignore: ':hidden:not("#ms")',
 rules: {
 //Rules and messages onwards
```

Above will fix the issue of validation,

And about data not posting, there is no `name=""` in `<select>` tag so add it one, and after validation, `<select>` value will be posted along with other inputs in `<form>`

```
<select style="display: none;" name="ms" id="ms" multiple="multiple" >
```

Comment: sorry to report that neither of these helped either issue. I added the rule to the ajax code as below     rules: {
    name: {
     required: true
    },
    email: {
     required: true,
     email: true
    },
    telephone: {
     required: true
    },
    message: {
     required: true
    },
    ms:{
     required: true,
     message: 'Please select at least one'
    },
    ignore: 'hidden:not(#ms)'
   }
and the name to the select as suggested. is there something plainly obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: it's there, I wouldn't be surprised if I put it in the wrong place though. in the  section last after ms: { "rules: {

Comment: yeah i know its there but at wrong place http://shehary.com/stackoverflow/multipleselect/index.php

Comment: it should be above rule and you are missing comma, should be ` ignore: ':hidden:not("#ms")', rules: {`

Comment: the link is up there, created form your original page, you can check the validation if empty and after filling all values, have to hit the button twice and values will be shown in alert one by one

Comment: also the multiple select jQuery, you need to read this http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#methods

Comment: and `<form>` i don't have clue why there is action `<form id="contactForm" action="js/contact-form.php" novalidate="novalidate">` on other hand you are trying to use `Ajax`

Comment: in your Ajax call, do not post values individually, you can use serialize method `var data = $('#contactForm').serialize();`, you can read more about it here http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ it should solve the Array problem

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try this and see where it leads me. My skills in this area are marginal at best, your time is much appreciated.